# How can i apply "current" class for category nav?

Tags: categories, navigation

I've browsed the questions and answers here and i can't find anything that works for what i'm trying to do!

I am using this as the main menu of my site (so it is in _layout.html)

```
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('artCats') %}
{% set entryCount = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).total()
  <li><a href="{{ category.url }}"><span>{{ category.title }}</span>{% if category.level == 2 %}<span class="postnum">({{ entryCount }})</span>{% endif %}</a>
  {% ifchildren %}
    <ul>
      {% children %}
    </ul>
  {% endifchildren %}
  </li>
{% endnav %}
```

It's a drop down menu that shows how many posts are in each sub category. All works nicely!

However, no matter what i try, i can't seem to dynamically assign a class to the current page. I think i'm misunderstanding in general how this is done in Craft.

I see a lot of solutions that are basically saying "if url segment is "fishcake" then add my class" but to me, that's not dynamic at all! Dynamic would be if i add a new sub-category, the menu will add my desired class to that menu item if i visit, without me having to add a new if statement in the Twig code.

Am i able to do something like "if the category.url of this link matches the current url, do this" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current Category Model via the pre-populated `category` variable on all of your category pages. (→ see [Routing type no. 4](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing))

As you probably know, entry pages come with `entry` pre-populated. To get all the Category Models that are related to an entry page with a Categories Field make a `craft.categories` call using `relatedTo(entry)` as a parameter.

Save the Category Model / -Models to a var outside your `nav` loop, so you don't have to make those requests multiple times. And make sure to save the one Category Model on category pages as an array `[myCategoryModel]`, so you always end up with your variable being of the same type.

Within you `nav` loop you can now check, if the Category Model of your current loop iteration is within your saved array using the [`in`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator) containment operator.

```
{# Is this an entry page with a category field? #}
{% if entry is defined %}
    {% set currentCategoryIds = craft.categories.relatedTo(entry).ids() %}
{# Is this a category page? #}
{% elseif category is defined %}
    {% set currentCategoryIds = [category.id] %}
{# None of both? Set an empty array. #}
{% else %}
    {% set currentCategoryIds = [] %}
{% endif %}

{% nav cat in craft.categories.group('artCats') %}

    {% set class = cat.id in currentCategoryIds ? 'current' : '' %}
    {% set entryCount = craft.entries.relatedTo(cat).total() %}

    <li><a href="{{ cat.url }}" class="{{ class }}">{{ cat.title }} ({{ entryCount }})</a></li>

{% endnav %}
```

Comment: If i do that, i get the following error: Variable "entry" does not exist. It highlights that very first line as where the error happens.
The site homepage doesn't throw that error, it only happens when i am in a category page like sitename.com/categoryname

Comment: @DanOwen Ahh sorry, I made the code to only work for entry pages (single, channel or structure entries with a categories field). Will try to change this...

Comment: @DanOwen I'm actually not sure if a category page automatically comes with a Category Model pre-assigned to the var `category`. If it does, the updated code could work ;)

Comment: @carlcs It does. I was wondering the same and just checked.

Comment: @carlcs Sounds good! BUT! It still throws that error for me on category list pages (it flag up the very first {% if entry %} as the error). That is, if a user clicks a category name, it lists all of the entries in that category (so im not in a page with a category field)

Comment: @DanOwen still no luck?

Comment: @carlcs Sorry for the slow reply! Well i don't get an error now. But now instead all of my links have class="" in them.

Comment: @DanOwen ok, it's probably the CategoryModels that make trouble with the `in` operator. Changed the code to use their IDs now, hope this helps.

Comment: @carlcs Same result again! I had to change what you have as cat.id to category.id else it threw an error. Thank you for your persistence on this! It's quite a head scratcher.

Comment: @DanOwen could you please try the whole code block as posted (remove all other nav)? I'm pretty sure this should work now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21190/discussion-between-carlcs-and-dan-owen).

Comment: @carlcs Yes! That did it :^) Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this!